# Script to disable "Show Characters" in the WIFI network properties

Tags: windows-7, windows, script, wifi-configuration

I want to know if it exist a script to disable the "Show Characters" check box in the WIFI network properties. I know it is possible to do it manually, but given that we have a lot of computer to manipulate, it would be great to have a script to do this job.

Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Many computers should not be sharing the same network password.  Look into using WPA Enterprise mode so that there will be no need to have a WiFi password that could be stolen/copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really disable the "show Characters" checkbox as it is part of the design, you best option is to make user your UAC settings is configured so only the admin can access this checkbox function with their credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us what method do you use to disable the checkbox manually. I assume you do this by changing registry permissions, as in uttams's answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/135665/windows-7-any-way-to-disable-show-caracter-in-wifi-network-properties?rq=1).

To change registry permissions from script you can use `regini.exe` from the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit. [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/245031/en-us) you will find how to do it.

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no due to possible future link-rot. Please include pertinent information directly in your answer(s) and cite the site as a source.